# Mastering flutter Wrap-Layout

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, word-wrap

I got a title and a description for some UI-element and want them to be placed among each other. The title and the description will vary from length. (as I don't know the length before build time)

This is my code:

```
Container(
  color: Colors.red,
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
  child: Wrap(
    direction: Axis.horizontal,
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 0, left: 15, right: 15),
        child: Text(
          "this is a test title",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
      Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 15, left: 15, right: 15),
          child: Text(
            "This is a test descripton This is a test descripton This is a test descripton This is a test descripton",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15),
          )),
    ],
  ))
```

It looks like this, which is what I want:

[image]

Also when the title and the description are long, it looks how I want it to look:

[image]

But when the title and the description are rather short, this happens:

[image]

They are now side-by-side which is not what I want. If I'd change the `direction` to `Axis.vertical`this would happen:

[image]

Looks good right?

But what if the title and description are long again?

[image]

Damn, now the text just overflows on the side.

Has anyone an idea on how to achieve what I want, no matter the length of my title and description? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Wrap` is the wrong widget for this task. To force widgets to display in a vertical arrangement like this, use a `Column` with `MainAxisSize.min`.

```dart
Container(
  color: Colors.red,
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
  child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 0, left: 15, right: 15),
        child: Text(
          "this is a test title",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 15, left: 15, right: 15),
        child: Text(
          "This is a test descripton This is a test descripton This is a test descripton This is a test descripton",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```